# Show number of orders by statuses and by custom ACF field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, orders

I'm working on a kind of internal 'plugin' to show how many orders currently I have with a split by statuses and account manager. So I would like to present it as a table like:

```
Account Manager | No of pending orders | No of canceled orders etc
```

I have such a piece of code:

```
function display_woocommerce_order_count( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed',
    ), $atts );
    $statuses    = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
    $order_count = 0;
    foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
        // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
            $status = 'wc-' . $status;
        }
        $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
    }
    ob_start();
    echo number_format( $order_count );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'display_woocommerce_order_count' );
```

On top of that I saw this code but im not sure how to use it:

```
public function get_customer_total_order() {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed' )
    ) );

    $total = 0;
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
        $total += $order->get_total();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

which adds a shortcode to display in general order number but without a breakdown to account manager. Through ACF I've created a custom field called `"handlowiec"` and assigned it to order screen. How to make it work?

Comment: You want to use get_customer_total_order() in shortcode or want to add No of pending and No of cancel Orders in display_woocommerce_order_count() ?

Comment: Please define account manager

Comment: @TejasSoni - as said i've just found this piece of code. Will not use it as a shortcode (but as a php code inside template file). So all in all wanted to make a loop just to show raw numbers

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier - sure. Account manager is a custom field added to the order screen (added via ACF). The field name is accountmanager. Do i need to provide field key?

Comment: @JuliaGalden no, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code, will count orders by status for the current Account manager ID corresponding to "handlowiec" ACF field:

[image]

So you will have to assign to each order to an Account manager ID:

[image]

The function code with a very light SQL query *(based on `wp_count_posts()` WordPress function)*:

```
function display_woocommerce_order_count( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed, processing, on-hold, cancelled',
        'handlowiec' => ''
    ), $atts );

    // Formatting the order statuses for the SQL query
    $statuses = $data = [];
    $statuses_array = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );

    foreach ( $statuses_array as $status ) {
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) )
            $statuses[] = 'wc-' . $status;
    }
    $statuses = implode("','", $statuses);

    ## -- 1. The SQL Query -- ##

    global $wpdb;
    $handlowiec_query = $join_postmeta = $output = '';

    // Handling the Account Manager ID (optionally)
    if( $args['handlowiec'] !== '' ){
        $join_postmeta = "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id";
        $handlowiec_query = "AND meta_key like 'handlowiec' AND meta_value = ";
        $handlowiec_query .= $args['handlowiec'];
    }

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        $join_postmeta
        WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND post_status IN ('$statuses')
        $handlowiec_query
        GROUP BY post_status
    ");

    ## -- 2. Formatting the Output -- ##

    // Loop through each order status count
    foreach($results as $result){
        $status = str_replace( 'wc-', '', $result->post_status );
        $orders_count = (int) $result->num_posts;

        if( $orders_count > 0 )
            $data[] =  ucfirst($status) . ' ' . _n( 'order', 'orders', $orders_count ) . ': ' . $orders_count;
    }
    if( $args['handlowiec'] !== '' )
        $output = 'Account Manager ID ' . $args['handlowiec'] . ' | ';
    else
        $output = 'All Account Managers | ';

    if( sizeof($data) > 0 )
        $output .= implode( ' | ', $data );
    else
        $output .= 'No results';

    return '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'display_woocommerce_order_count' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

USAGE:

1) Without an "Account Manager ID" (for all managers):

```
 echo do_shortcode("[wc_order_count]");
```

> You will get something like:
>
> ```
> All Account Managers | On-hold orders: 2 | Processing orders: 7 | …
> ```

2) With a specific "Account Manager ID":

```
echo do_shortcode("[wc_order_count handlowiec='5']");
```

> You will get something like:
>
> ```
> Account Manager ID 5 | On-hold order: 1 | Processing orders: 3 | …
> ```

You can also use as before `status` argument to specify which orders status will be involved in the output…